# cv2 Python: How to get the hierarchy of a specific contour?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get the hierarchy of a specific contour. Given an image with multiple random contours, I know the contour I need has the largest area by far (>1000). Its easy to sort contours by their area and then select the first one in the list. But I can't figure out how to sort the hierarchy to match the sorted contours.

My code looks like this:

```
_, vs_conts, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask[2, :, :], cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
vs_conts = [c for c in vs_conts if cv.contourArea(c) > 1000]
vs_conts = sorted(vs_conts, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]
        
holes = hierarchy[0][0][2]
if holes != -1:
        image_health_flag = 1
```

I either need for the hierarchy to be sorted the same way as the contours, or I need to be able to find the hierarchy of a specific contour based only on the contour returned after the sorted function

Comment: What is your OpenCV version?

Comment: opencv 3.3.1 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for my specific need: By zipping and sorting through the hierarchy and only grabbing contours that have no parent but DO have children, I can then sort through those contours by area, and if the largest area contour is in the list, then it has children and therefore has holes (which is why I needed to sort the hierarchy).

```
    _, fold_conts, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask[1, :, :], cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Grab all contours w/ no parents, but do have children
    hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions => [next,previous,child,parent]
    parent_conts = [c[0] for c in zip(fold_conts, hierarchy) if c[1][3] == -1 and c[1][2] > -1]
    parent_conts = [c for c in parent_conts if cv.contourArea(c) > 1000]
    if parent_conts:
        flag = 1
```